# I keep getting this error when i try to run require('opencv4nodejs'). MODULE_NOT_FOUND even though opencv4nodejs is installed on my mac. Help me?

Tags: node.js, opencv

Upon countless error codes, I finally installed opencv4nodejs after running this command: export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1 beforehand
However, when i try to call opencv4nodejs through the require('opencv4nodes') command, I get this error:
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs'
Require stack:

- /Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js
- /Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js
- /Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/test.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
  at Object. (/Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:40:8)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  '/Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js',
  '/Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js',
  '/Users/ambikanepal/Desktop/Opencv/test.js'

CAN YOU HELP ME FIND A SOLUTION TO THIS PROBLEM?

I disabled autobuild before installing opencv4nodejs. The installation was successful but I cannot call it in my program.

My setup:
M1 macos Ventura
Node 16.20.2
Npm 8.19.7
OpenCV 4.8.1_1 (I installed this through brew).